# javascript attempting to set element display to none after page load echos 'none'

Tags: javascript, html

When typing the following into a browser url bar once a page has been displayed, I would expect the referenced element to be hidden. However, what actually happens is the contents of the window is cleared and the word "none" is echoed out to the screen (as if I had issued a document.write command)

```
javascript: {document.getElementById('footer').style.display="none";}
```

This has worked for me in the past. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: always nice to receive a downvote with no feedback as to why! :(

Comment: Agree. I think your question is already clear enough because I could answer to it.

Comment: @tkhm Except you misunderstood it. But I think it's clear enough.

Comment: @Barmar. I edited the question slightly after tkhm's response in order the clarify, so the confusion was understandable

Comment: I see the same behavior when I try this here in SO, using `question-header` as the ID. Very strange. But the console still shows the old DOM.

Answer (score -1):

Which browser and version are you use?

According to Mozilla, the function you mentioned is disabled on Firefox version 40 and later.

[Browser Console - Firefox Developer Tools | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)

> NB: The Browser Console command line (to execute JavaScript expressions) is disabled by default. To enable it set the devtools.chrome.enabled preference to true in about:config, or set the "Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes" (Firefox 40 and later)  option in the developer tool settings.

If you want to enable it, you must change the setting. This link page might be helpful for you.

[Settings - Firefox Developer Tools | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Settings)

1. Open the development tools setting
2. Look up the advanced setting
3. Tick on the `Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes`

Comment: Interesting. I am able to execute other javascript though; for example if I do javascript: {window.alert('hello');} it does display the window alert, so I don't think that's whats causing the problem

Comment: He's not using the console, he's typing a bookmarklet into the URL bar.